# ^a-zA-Z0-9 excluding spaces?

Tags: regex, spaces

I am trying to find everything in a paragraph that is not abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 and not space / /gi

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^ ]/gi
```

the above doesn't work!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also try with:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/gi
```

Comment: better because \s  will match tab/newline whitespace too, which is what you'd want. Note that you can use \w in most regex flavors to mean: letters+numbers+underscores, underscores are valid alphanumerics:  /[^\w\s]/gi

Answer (score 10):

If you only want to exclude spaces use:

```
[^ ]*
```

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

try `^[\d\w]*$`  or ^[\w]*$
as reg' Expression means from `^(start)` to `$(end)` match `0-9a-zA-Z`  only

for c++  `ansistring="^[\\d\\w]*$";`

Comment: Nice one, +1. If u want to exclude empty string `^[\d\w]+$`

Comment: `\w` already includes `\d` so you can remove `\d` from character class. It also includes `_` that is not wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for 
 am trying to find everything in a paragraph that is not abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 and not space / /gi

```
replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]", "")
```

Comment: You have answered a question where an answers was already provided and one accepted, and your answer does not provide any new information to what was already answered. If you have additional information apart from what was already provided, please add that to your answer