# SQL Sever 2012+ to return non-alphanumeric characters, excluding spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-alphanumeric

Ok, have tried [^a-zA-Z0-9], [^a-zA-Z0-9 ] (LIKE OR NOT LIKE), as well as PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',mycol) > 0

None of these exclude spaces and therefore always return valid entries- I want only those with non-numeric, non-alpha, and non-space.  I *know* I have a record with HTML code in one varchar field.  I also know I have special characters such as ?, #,*, ect.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Well to ignore numbers you can use where ISNUMERIC(field) = 0 and CHARINDEX(' ' , field) = 0 -- for spaces and REPLACE(REPLACE(PARTNO,'/', ''),'-','') LIKE '%D12A%' -- Extend the non-alphanumer characers, give it a try might work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [^a-zA-Z0-9 excluding spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626283/a-za-z0-9-excluding-spaces)

Comment: When I said spaces, I mean spaces between valid character (ex, a name), not JUST a space - I'm not clear on what the Replace (Replace(.. would do.  These are NAME fields I'm executing it on, and I want to return ANY special characters that are non-alphanumeric, ignoring spaces.  The examples provided are still returning valid entries.  The referenced formula in the linked post (/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/gi) does not work on SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: I also tried LIKE '%[!@#$%&*()_-+={}[]/?|\~`.]%' with no success

Comment: Replace `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%` with `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%` (i.e. add a space to the chars you're matching)

Comment: @JohnLBevan - tried that too, it still returns VALID records.  Ex, " SMITH  " (leading and trailing (multiple) spaces is VALID - "SMITH #?" would NOT be a valid entry.  In the case of the conditions provided, the VALID record is always returned.